# R6010: Can I pass an int& to a function that accepts an int?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have a function declared something like

```
void func1(int& x) {
    func2(x); // func2 accepts an int
}
```

I think this is what crashes the program? I get the error

> `R6010 - abort() has been called`

What do I need to do to pass x into a function that accepts an int? I expected them to work the same ... since I can just echo the value of x using `cout << x`

**UPDATE**

Just a test:

```
cout << stmtNo << endl;
Node* n = ast->getNode(stmtNo);
cout << n->getNodeType() << " " << n->getStmtNo() << endl;
```

Above fails ... Below passes

```
cout << stmtNo << endl;
Node* n = ast->getNode(1);
cout << n->getNodeType() << " " << n->getStmtNo() << endl;
```

Comment: "I think this is what crashes the program" did you debug?

Comment: Yes I changed the call from `func2(x)` to `func2(1)` and it worked ... not sure seems like thats the problem ... tho ... I'm not the one that made `func2()` ... and am also new to C++

Comment: what does the call to `func1()` look like?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I updated the qn with what I did to think that the variable is the problem ...

Comment: @juanchopanza, here u go http://pastie.org/5176441. The offending line appears to be 20 ...

Comment: Replace `Node* n = ast->getNode(1);` with `int x=1; Node* n = ast->getNode(x);` and see if it passes as well.

Comment: Where is `ast` defined? What does `getNode` do?

Comment: Where does `stmtNo` come from originally? It's passed into your function, so chances are this is an invalid reference.

Comment: You can’t actually pass a reference to anything—no expression ever has reference type.  You can pass an lvalue, though, and it would be more than a little surprising if you couldn’t!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem, you can always pass an integer reference as an argument for an integer.

Integer references can be interpreted as constant pointers who automatically de-reference themselves.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun_2(int s)
{
   cout<<s<<endl;
}
void func(int &d)
{
    fun_2(d);
}

int main()
{
   int x=99;
   func(x);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

The above code works perfectly!